# Ef core migration with different startup project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I have one project with my Azure functions which is going to work as an API.
Then I have a separate "core" project, with my efcore, dbcontext and models.

I have added a configurator class in the core project that looks like this:

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddDatabaseContext(this IServiceCollection services, Action<DatabaseOptions> configureOptions)
{
    services.Configure(configureOptions);
    services.AddDbContextPool<SampleApiDbContext>((provider, options) =>
    {
        var dbOptions = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<DatabaseOptions>>().CurrentValue;
        options.UseSqlServer(dbOptions.ConnectionString, b=> b.MigrationsAssembly("Dymak.SampleLibraryApi.Admin"));
    });

    return services;
}
```

And my startup class in the api project.

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        string sqlConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");

        builder.Services.AddDatabaseContext(options => 
        { 
            options.ConnectionString = sqlConnection; 
        });
    }
}
```

For reference my dbcontext.

```
public class SampleApiDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SampleApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<SampleApiDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    public SampleApiDbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Models.TagType> Types { get; set; } = null!;
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Any time I run the command

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ..\Dymak.SampleLibraryApi migrations add Initial
```

I get the following error message

```
Unable to create an object of type 'SampleApiDbContext'. For different patterns.......
```

I have not been able to find a solution to my problem, so I'm hoping someone here might know.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand the question - but why does API project even matter? If you are in your core project, you should be able to run `dotnet ef` without specifying `--startup-project`. If you *have to* specify - then there is a different process; namely, something is wrong without core project itself

Comment: *"For different patterns......."* actually contains a link to the documentation explaining the possible approaches for [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). Most likely you need to take [From a design-time factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) approach.

Comment: I have more than one project which all will have a reference to the core project, so since the core project will never run by it self, I have the startup configuration made like that. So it should work in any project I need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems since I'm using azure functions, that it's not possible to do since EntityFramework Migrations are not capable of auto-discovering my migrations in an Azure Function.

So I had to create a separate class where I created a IDesignTime factory. (in the core project)

```
public class SampleApiDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<SampleApiDbContext>
{
    public SampleApiDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SampleApiDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("random string");

        return new SampleApiDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

It did solve some of my issues, and it appears, I cannot get it to automatically make the migration. But this will still work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to reference your target (core) project in the ef migrations add command?

```
dotnet ef --project <project-where-you-have-dbcontext> --startup-project ..\Dymak.SampleLibraryApi migrations add Initial
```

Comment: The error is saying "Unable to create an object of type 'SampleApiDbContext'`. So the tool knows the context class type (hence the project containing it)